# Design a CFG for $L=\{ w \in \{ 0,1 \}^* \}$, where $w$ contains at least three ones

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata, context-free, formal-grammars

$L=\{ w \in \{ 0,1 \} \}$ **where $w$ contains at least three ones**

Here is one solution for the productions:

$S \to A1A1A1A$

$A \to 1A | 0A | \epsilon$

However, now I have a question. Could I modify the second rule to be as follows:

$A \to A1 | A0 | \epsilon$

What I did was just switch the places of the non-terminals and terminals in the second rule. For most of the words I tried, this grammar also works well. What is the difference between writing $1A$ and $A1$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can safely modify the rules for $A$. In this particular case, the order ($A1$ vs. $1A$) makes no difference in the language generated by your grammar.

The difference is in the way how words are generated (derived) using your grammar.

When the rules for $A$ are the former ($A \to 1A \mid 0A \mid \varepsilon$, the derivation can be (for example) $S \Rightarrow A1A1A1A \Rightarrow 0A1A1A1A \Rightarrow 01A1A1A \Rightarrow 011A1A1A \Rightarrow 0111A1A \dots$.

While in the latter form, the derivation can look like $S \Rightarrow A1A1A1A \Rightarrow A01A1A1A \Rightarrow 01A1A1A \dots$

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you need to understand very carefully Chomsky Hierarchy for
$Type-0,Type-1,Type-2,Type-3$ grammar. Then you perceive all the grammar and production rules, restrictions for respective $Type.$

Alone the grammar $A \rightarrow 1A|0A|\epsilon$ is under $Type-3$ grammar which is known as Right-Linear-Grammar. If you are writing production which is $Type-3$ then you could use only one production which either Right-Linear or Left-Linear at a time not the both at same time.

But your written grammar in the question is the grammar which is under $Type-2$ that's why it has less restrictions than $Type-3$, it's allowed both Right-Linear or Left-Linear at a time or combination of both are allowed.